# Regex: How to specify a range in hex covering a collection of Unicode symbols

Tags: c#, regex, hex

I have an XML document that contains an invalid character (Hex: 0x2642). More from [here](http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/info/9794). I want to remove it before deserializing the document. XML is represented as a string when we strip it off of invalid characters. So far, we've used:

```
var xmlString = Regex.Replace(xmlString, @"[^\u0000-\uF000]", string.Empty);
```

It worked for control characters but instead of specifying the 0x2642, I wanted to create a range in regex that covers a range of symbols to avoid this issue in the future (specifically these symbols [here](http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/block/Miscellaneous_Symbols.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify the linked symbols of the MiscellaneousSymbols block
you can use the regex:

`\p{IsMiscellaneousSymbols}`

to match them in c#.

---

C# uses `\p{IsBlock}` for Unicode blocks.